# Apply a one day offset to x axis in Grafana (Prometheus data source)

Tags: grafana

I've created a metric to count unique ids in a data set over the day yesterday and am scraping it into prometheus. So say yesterday's count was 100, this value will be reported throughout today until tomorrow, when today's tally will be computed an then reported throughout tomorrow.

So far so good. Now when I display the value 100 in Grafana, it will show it with today's date, when the actual value is actually yesterday's.

Is there a way to simply offset the x axis in Grafana by `-1d` to make the dates and values align again, i.e. to change the scrape date to the 'value' date, if you will?

I know there's a 'time shift' in Grafana, but that will just offset the scrape date. I'm also aware of prometheus' 'offset' operator, which will do the same.

What I'm looking for is simply to tell Grafana that it should display 'now' as 'now-1d'.

I've found a setting on the dashboard level that is labeled "Now delay now-". However, this also doesn't shift the x axis and does nothing to change the display.

Grafana version 4.1.1, Prometheus version 1.5.3

Answer (score 0):

To achieve described behavior you can simply use Prometheus' [`offset`](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/#offset-modifier) modifier.

```
mymetric offset 1d
```

It will produce time series shifted for 1 day back.

Since [2.33](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md#2330--2022-01-29) you also can use negative offset.